# How do I output the two new strings in main function in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to write a program where a char array is initialized and split into 2 new c style strings without the connecting character. When I use the void function as a separate program it works but when I call it in my main function it doesnt. Is my way of calling the function incorrect or is there some mistake in the way of writing the code? The program works like this: The chara array is initialized as Frenk+Harizaj and the void functions checks every character until it reaches +, assigns it to sName, then continues checking after the +, assigns it to sSurname and outputs both strings

````
       #include <iostream>
       using namespace std;

       void splitter(char s[])
       {

           int i, x, counter;
           char sName[20]="";
           char sSurname[20]="";

           for(i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
           {
               counter++;
           }

           for (i=0; i!='+'; i++)
           {
               sName[i]=s[i];

               if(s[i+1]=='+')
               {
                   for(x=i+2; x<counter; x++)
                   {
                       sSurname[x-(i+2)]=s[x];
                   }
                   i=counter;
               }
           }

           cout<<"Name: "<<sName<<endl;
           cout<<"Surname: "<<sSurname<<endl;
       }



       int main()
       {
           int a, b;
           int i=0, j=0, k=0; 

           char s[]="Frenk+Harizaj";

           char firstName[10], lastName[10], fullName[20], character[2];

           cout<<"Press 1 to merge two strings: "<<endl;
           cout<<"Press 2 to split two strings: "<<endl;
           cin>>a;

           if(a==1)
           {
               cout<<"Enter your first name: ";
               cin.ignore();
               cin.getline(firstName, 15);

               cout<<"Enter your last name: ";
               cin.getline(lastName, 15);
               cout<<endl;

               cout<<"Connecting character: "<<endl;
               cout<<"Press 1 for no connecting character "<<endl;
               cout<<"Press 2 to enter connecting character "<<endl;

               cin>>b;

               if(b==1)
               {
                   for(i; firstName[i]!='\0'; i++)
                   {
                       fullName[i]=firstName[i];
                   }


                   for(i, j; lastName[j]!='\0'; i++, j++)
                   {
                       fullName[i]=lastName[j];
                   }

                   cout<<fullName;
               }

               else if(b==2)
               {
                   cout<<"Enter the connecting character: ";
                   cin.ignore();
                   cin.getline(character, 2);

                   for(i; firstName[i]!='\0'; i++)
                   {
                       fullName[i]=firstName[i];
                   }

                   for(i, k; character[k]!='\0'; i++, k++)
                   {
                       fullName[i]=character[k];
                   }

                   for(i, j; lastName[j]!='\0'; i++, j++)
                   {
                       fullName[i]=lastName[j];
                   }

                   cout<<fullName;
               }
           }

           if(a==2)
           {   
               splitter(s);
           }


       }
   ```
````

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that loop that counts characters should be replaced by a call to `strlen`. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I could recommend lot of changes in your code, like using C++ standard strings instead of C style strings, do proper bounds checking etc., the simplest changes that would fix your code are:

(1) Initialize `counter` variable to 0 in `splitter` function
(2) Inner `for` loop is written wrongly as `for (i=0; i!='+'; i++)`. It should be `for (i=0; i < counter; i++)`

Comment: Yes it is obligatory to use c style strings

Comment: Made the changes you suggested and the code worked. Thankyou very much

Comment: There is 1 thing that Im not quite getting tho. MAking that change to the for loop, how come the loop copies only the characters before + and not all the characters to sName? Beacuse it continues until the end.

Comment: Your check ```if(s[i+1]=='+')``` and looping starting from ```i+2``` thereon is taking care of that.

Comment: Pretty clear. Last thing. When I output in sName it outputs as Name: Frenk: and when I remove " : " from cout<<"Name: " it is also removed from sName output

Comment: Made some changes to the code, declared sName and sSurname as sName[counter]; and sSurname[counter ]; after the counter loop and now it works fine. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, when you need to do two separate things, they belong in two separate blocks of code. In particular, copying the second half of the input from inside the loop that copies the first part is confusing. Just write two loops:

```
// first copy first part of input string
for (int i = 0; i < counter && s[i] != '+'; ++i)
     sName[i] = s[i];
sName[i] = '\0'; // append nul terminator

// then copy second part of input string
if (s[i] == '+') {
    ++i;
    int j = 0;
    for ( ; i < counter; ++i, ++j)
        sSurname[j] = s[i];
    sSurname[j] = '\0';
}
```

But most of this code can be replaced with functions from the standard library:

```
const char *plus_loc = std::strchr(s, '+');
if (plus_loc) {
    int plus_offset = plus_loc - s;
    std::strncpy(sName, s, plus_offset);
    sName[plus_offset] = '\0';
    std::strcpy(sSurname, plus_offset + 1);
}
```